# Add PHP code to header section from plugin

Tags: hooks, wp-head

How can i add any type of PHP code to header section through plugin programmatically ?

I did use

```
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
   function your_function()
      {
         echo 
            'if(isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"]))
               {
                  echo "geting";exit;
               }';
      }
```

but its not working as a PHP script, Its just **echo** this as a **string** in head section.

Thanks!

Comment: It echoes it as a string, because you're doing exactly that - you say to echo that string in `wp_head`. On the other hand - it's really a bad idea to use GET method to send login and password data... And you really should NOT process such data in header...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work better

```
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
function your_function() {
    if(isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"])){
        echo "geting";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i add wordpress login code here like **wp_signon** ?

Comment: You can add any code inside `wp_head` action, but beware that it will execute on every request. Read more in codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head